# MySQL group_concat twice in SubQuery DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have table like this:

```
title   name
1   ADAM SMITH
1   JACK SMITH
1   ROBERT ABADI
2   JACK SMITH
2   JAMES ANDERSON
3   JACK SMITH
```

When I call data with query looks like

```
SELECT title, name, group_concat(name) as gname
FROM sample
GROUP BY title
```

The result is:

```
1   ADAM SMITH  ADAM SMITH,JACK SMITH,ROBERT ABADI
2   JACK SMITH  JACK SMITH,JAMES ANDERSON
3   JACK SMITH  JACK SMITH
```

Now, I want to group by name again. so I call this query and results is following.

```
SELECT title, name, group_concat(distinct gname)
FROM
(
SELECT title, name, group_concat(name) as gname
FROM sample
GROUP BY title
) sub
GROUP BY sub.name


1   ADAM SMITH  ADAM SMITH,JACK SMITH,ROBERT ABADI
2   JACK SMITH  JACK SMITH,JAMES ANDERSON,JACK SMITH
```

But I don't want to have the '`JACK SMITH`' twice on last column.

I know the reason because the first `group_concat()` results is string that can't not applied with '`DISTINCT`' clause.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your first query doesn't make sense. The `name` column is just a randomly selected name from the `title` group, why would you then want to group on that?

Comment: I want to know the who (author) belongs to same title (paper). So first query will show gname (co-author). This table and data is just sample. The table has first, middle, last name and title. So we would like to know first co-author by each paper. Does it make sense more? Thanks @Barmar

Comment: But you'll get totally different results depending on whether the subquery selects Jack Smith or James Anderson as the author of title 2.

Comment: I am trying to get all the co-authors of an author. The first column is the id of a publication. The next three columns are the first, middle and last names of an author. @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` to get co-authors:

```
SELECT s1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s2.name)
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2 ON s1.title = s2.title
GROUP BY s1.name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0210/2)

If you don't want to show an author as a co-author of himself, add `AND s1.name != s2.name` to the `ON` condition.

Comment: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6765c/1) I want to know the number of common co authors. Can you see the link and answer it?

Comment: Add `COUNT(distinct s2.name) AS num`?

Comment: updated the SQLfiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb2cf/1) Not the number of co-authors but common co-authors. Look at the 'JACK S SMITH'. He has no coauthors in common with JACK SMITH. Can we continue this discussion in a chat room if possible? Maybe we could explain better through chat. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You should ask a new question, and show the output you're trying to get.

Comment: Here is the question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973941/mysql-count-the-common-data-in-a-column-resulted-from-group-concat)