# MySQL count the common data in a column resulted from group_concat()

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to find the number of coauthors who are common between certain authors - When the first name and the last name of the authors is the same and one of the authors has no middle name.

In such scenarios, we are interested to find the number of coauthors who are common to the author with no middle name with the authors with middle names.

For example, [link] http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75243/1

In this table, we have authors with multiple middle names but the same first and last names i.e, `JACK SMITH, JACK A SMITH, JACK B SMITH`. We are interested to find the number of coauthors common to

```
1. JACK SMITH with JACK A SMITH
2. JACK SMITH with JACK B SMITH
```

The result would include num field result as

```
JACK A SMITH  1
JACK B SMITH  0
```

since `JACK A SMITH` has one coauthor in common with `JACK SMITH` and `JACK B SMITH` has no coauthors in common with `JACK SMITH`.

Comment: so you smush a bunch of different fields together and group_concat it, and now have to tear apart that derived column to get back to the original nicely separated data? Why not just access the original raw data, BEFORE it got concatted together? It'd be **FAR** easier doing that than trying to teach your DB how to parse people's names

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` with multiple columns. So you can use this to count the different full names without actually having to concatenate them first.

```
SELECT s1.fname, s1.mname, s1.lname, s1.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s2.fname, s2.mname, s2.lname) as num
FROM ( SELECT title, fname, mname, lname, CONCAT(fname, ' ',mname, ' ', lname) as name
  FROM sample ) as s1
LEFT JOIN sample AS s2
ON s1.title = s2.title AND s1.fname = s2.fname AND s1.lname = s2.lname AND s1.mname != s2.mname 
WHERE s1.mname != ''
GROUP BY s1.name
ORDER BY s1.lname, s1.fname, s1.mname
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` rather than `JOIN` in order to get the rows with zero coauthors.

Comment: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83e5ed/1) thanks, we added 'HENRY FORD' and the results should be HENRY A FORD as 0 and HENRY B FORD as 1 but not.

Comment: None of the Henry Fords are coauthors because they have different titles.

Comment: HENRY B FORD and HENRY FORD have common coauthor JACK SMITH (see titles 2,3). Hence the count of HENRY B FORD should be 1.

Comment: Your question says you only want to count coauthors who have the same first and last name, but different middle names. My answer doesn't count Jack Smith with Henry Ford because the first and last names are different.

Comment: Is there any way to have the number of common co-authors about HENRY FORD? Thanks in advance

Comment: You got that answer in the other question you asked.

Comment: @Barmar But the count for HENRY B FORD and HENRY A FORD is 0 in the fiddle - should not that be having the count of the number of coauthors they have in common with HENRY FORD?

Comment: The question says _When the first name and the last name of the authors is the same_. So I'm only counting those coauthors, not any of the other coauthrs.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. So for HENRY FORD, HENRY A FORD and HENRY B FORD, their first and last names are the same. We need to compute the coauthor count. For the coauthors, can we get the count without any specification?

Comment: They're not coauthors because they don't have any of the same titles. HENRY is title 3, HENRY A is title 4, HENRY B is title 2.

Comment: @Barmar But the question says - "When the first name and the last name of the **authors** is the same". Also HENRY A FORD and HENRY B FORD have a common coauthor JACK SMITH. So should not the count of HENRY B FORD be 1?

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to add a COUNT ...

```
SELECT s1.fname, s1.mname, s1.lname, s1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s2.name) as coauthor, COUNT(DISTINCT s2.name) as num
FROM ( SELECT title, fname, mname, lname, CONCAT(fname, ' ', IF(mname is null, '', CONCAT(mname, ' ')), lname) as name
  FROM sample ) as s1
JOIN ( SELECT title, fname, mname, lname, CONCAT(fname, ' ', IF(mname is null, '', CONCAT(mname, ' ')), lname) as name
  FROM sample ) AS s2
ON s1.title = s2.title AND s1.name != s2.name
GROUP BY s1.name
ORDER BY s1.lname, s1.fname, s1.mname
```